# How to pass select-options value to button onclick in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, jsx

I can pass the value of my select-options but I change my mind and want to pass the value first on the button for onClick function.. Thanks

```js
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
const Purchase = () => {
  const products = useSelector(state => state.products);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const purchaseHandler = e => {
      let pName = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text;
      let price = e.target.value;
      let obj = { pName, price };
      dispatch({ type: "PURCHASE", payLoad: obj });
  };
  return (
      <div>
          <select onChange={e => purchaseHandler(e)}>
              {products.map((product, index) => {
                  return (
                      <option value={product.price} key={index}>
                          {product.pName} - ${product.price}
                      </option>
                  );
              })}
          </select>
          <button onClick={purchaseHandler} className="addToCart">
              Add to Cart
          </button>
      </div>
  );
};
export default Purchase;
```

Comment: So you will have to use useState() hook to set the values from your select handler, then you can do this on the button onClick={(e)=>anotherHandler(values)} This should do the necessary, If you can give a example in codesandbox, it will be even more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `productIndex` when selection changes and get the `product` from `products` array using index when clicking the button.

Try like below

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const Purchase = () => {
    const products = useSelector(state => state.products);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [productIndex, setProductIndex] = useState(0);

    const purchaseHandler = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "PURCHASE", payLoad: products[productIndex] });
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <select
                onChange={e => {
                    setProductIndex(e.target.value);
                }}
            >
                {products.map((product, index) => {
                    return (
                        <option value={index} key={index}>
                            {product.pName} - ${product.price}
                        </option>
                    );
                })}
            </select>
            <button onClick={purchaseHandler} className="addToCart">
                Add to Cart
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Purchase;
```

[image: Edit wonderful-banzai-dbwgk]